# ImpactJS and HammerJS mouse input conflicts with one another

Tags: javascript, html, hammer.js, impactjs

I'm building a game using the ImpactJS engine (http://impactjs.com/). The game requires gestures such as drag and swipe. Hence, HammerJS is integrated on the code.

In the snippet below, the release event callback is not triggered when the left click is binded as ig.input.

```
init : function() {
    // The onRelease() is triggered when this is commented out.
    //ig.input.bind( ig.KEY.MOUSE1, "click" );

    Hammer( this.canvas ).on( "dragup", this.onDragUp.bind( this ) );
    Hammer( this.canvas ).on( "dragdown", this.onDragDown.bind( this ) );
    Hammer( this.canvas ).on( "release", this.onRelease.bind( this ) );
},

onRelease : function() {
    alert( "Released!" );
}

onDragUp : function( event ) { 
    //No problem here.
}

onDragDown : function( event ) {
   //No problem here.
}
```

What seems to be the problem here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
Hammer( this.canvas ).on( "dragup", this.onDragUp.bind( this ), {prevent_default: true} );
```

https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/538